# Need file to Automatically save as a new document in a shared folder

Tags: command-line

I am currently using the code below when clicking a command button. Ultimately, this takes the template document and saves as a new document. Unfortunately, it doesn't automatically save it and it just gives me this -

[image]

```
Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()
 
    CommandButton1.Select
    Selection.Delete
 
    MsgBox ("Compiling New RCA Submission.")

    With Application.FileDialog(msoFileDialogSaveAs)
        .FilterIndex = 1
        .Show
        
        If .SelectedItems.Count <> 0 Then
            ThisDocument.SaveAs2 .SelectedItems(1), wdFormatXMLDocument
        End If
    End With

    MsgBox ("New RCA submitted.")
      
 
End Sub
```

What I want it to do is automatically save in a shared file in sharepoint. I also want it to automatically save as in sequential order, so that every time the button is pressed, it saves it as an updated one. See the nomenclature below :
4.1.1.  RCA nomenclature -
PHX – RCA YEAR – Sequential Number
PHX – RCA 23 – XXXX

I also want the sequential number to be located in the RCA number portion of this table every time the template is opened, the most recent "New" number appears.

[image]

```
Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()
 
    CommandButton1.Select
    Selection.Delete
 
    MsgBox ("Compiling New RCA Submission.")

    With Application.FileDialog(msoFileDialogSaveAs)
        .FilterIndex = 1
        .Show
        
        If .SelectedItems.Count <> 0 Then
            ThisDocument.SaveAs2 .SelectedItems(1), wdFormatXMLDocument
        End If
    End With

    MsgBox ("New RCA submitted.")
      
 
End Sub
```